# How to write CSS for a web-based mobile app?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following design that I want to code for a mobile web-based app. I have attached a picture [image]

so I have split it between 3 main sections, header, footer, and content.

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 left: 0
}

.footer {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 left: 0
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; bottom: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding-left:10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
```

I want to make sure that only the content within the content block is scrollable in a vertical direction, if necessary.

What I'm having the most trouble with is position the stuff within the content as it is in the image.

For example, the form element must be vertically centered between the paragraph and the text block at the bottom.

I made a block for the hey object, the paragraph object, the form element, and the text object. In the image the borders containing the object where just placed there by the application I used to draw the diagram, so just picture the content, except for the image in the background, which could be any shape, but still in that location.

```
.hey-object {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-left: 12%;
}

.paragraph {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12%;
}

.input-box {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 15%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 12%;
}

.text-object {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

One of the biggest issues I deal with is positioning the content in each of the above elements vertically, for example the form element should be exactly in the middle of the paragraph and the text object, the text object should be right above the footer. There should be the amount of space visually represented in the image, between the hey-object and the paragraph object.

For the image, I'm just thinking of absolutely placing it.

I'm just generally looking for tips on how to better write my css, or anything that can help me deal with the issues I wrote. Since this will be deployed as part of an app, the screen sizes of the devices will change, so I'm hoping for the end result to scale well.

Comment: try playing around with flexbox: http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html